# MS Edge won't display images on facebook.com (privateNetworkClientServer error)

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge

I'm having a problem where all of a sudden MS Edge stopped displaying images on facebook.com, instagram.com and in the Instagram Win10 app.

The developer console on Edge reports these error when trying to load images on facebook.com:

```
SEC7117: Network request to https://scontent.flju1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p32x32/12963550_1173816075984724_109813106519000750_n.jpg?oh=ce9840c9687842c0bdd4180d3676e3ac&oe=5895CCA9 did not succeed.
This Internet Explorer instance does not have the following capabilities: privateNetworkClientServer
```

I've researched a lot (even here on stackoverflow) and the problem seems to be because:

> "...all Metro-style apps running on Windows 8 will run in
>   AppContainer, as well as all tabs running in IE 10 with EPM turned on.
>   He described AppContainer as a "tight sandbox" because it "does not
>   specify internetClientServer, privateNetworkClientServer,
>   enterpriseAuthentication, or any of the *Library capabilities."

That's all fine and great, but if I open facebook.com with IE11 the images are shown and there are no errors in the console. I've already tried resetting/changing my security zones in IE, enabling/disabling Enhanced Protection Mode in IE. etc, etc,... Each time, images are not shown in Edge (or the Instagram metro app), but shown in IE (or Chrome).

Also I've already reset (aka "reinstalled") Edge multiple times (through powershell) and no luck. As I said, as far as I know only images hosted on facebook.com and Instagram.com are not shown. That means even when viewing an Instagram post through a reddit metro app, the images are not shown or when using the Instagram win10 app.

So are there any settings or registry tweaks for AppContainer that could cause this. Because I certainly didn't make any changes to either Edge or IE to cause this. This just started happening all of a sudden a few weeks back. So I'm guessing an update broke something in the registry or something.

Any help would be much appreciated, because I've almost given up on this.

Comment: UPDATE: If I DISABLE the built in Windows Firewall the problem goes away. But only if I disable/stop the firewall service. Even if I disable all the rules in the firewall, the images are still not loaded. Only disabling the firewall seems to fix the problem. But you can't run Win1' metro apps when the firewall is disabled so that's not a solution. Also, when using Fiddler the problem is not there. So there is definitely something with AppContainer messed up on my machine, because it doesn't give the _privateNetworkClientServer _ capabilities to any app it seems.